# Best fit line for a series of 3D points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, 3d

I have been trying to calculate the line of best fit for a series of 3D points. 
For example, my points are $(10,10,12)$, $(8,5,11)$, $(10,8,5)$, $(15,10,12)$. I want to find a line that will best fit these points.

I have no idea how to do it using mathematical equations. I am a developer with minimal knowledge in mathematical equations. Anyone please suggest a way to solve this issue.

Comment: Look up 'linear regression'

Comment: Have you tried graphing your points? That way you can visually see where your line of best fit needs to lie.

Comment: What is the measure of error? There are three different axes you can be  parallel to, and you could also measure the distance from the points to the line itself.

Comment: As i already mentioned above i have minimal knowledge in mathematics. I know linear regression can solve my problem. But while i am checking the sites, the answers are too difficult to understand. Can you guys please explain the solution in a more simple way.